# If I repair my Windows XP installation, will it damage the dual-boot setup I have with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm running Windows XP SP2 alongside Ubuntu 12.04 (for legacy compatibility), but after some failed Windows updates I think my only option is to perform a Windows repair.

If I do that, will (or could) it damage the dual-boot Ubuntu setup?

I just want to prepare myself (and my wife!) for a couple of lengthy nights re-installation if that's the case...

Comment: I think it will. But you don't have to do any re-installation. Repairing the boot loader is pretty simple and takes just few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A Windows "repair" will break the Ubuntu the bootloader (grub) by replacing it with Windows' own. XP is completely oblivious to Linux operating systems and won't offer to give you a dual-boot choice.

That's not the end of the world because you can just reinstall GRUB after you're done fixing XP and for that you have several choices outlined in full by the Ubuntu Wiki:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

The key element is that you're prepared for this. Burn and test a Ubuntu Live CD or Live USB stick before you set off so that when you're don with Windows, it's just a case of hopping into the Live environment and firing a few commands off to fix everything up.